# Trying to disable guest account gives 2 accounts

Tags: login, guest-account

After upgrading to High Sierra, I have 2 guest accounts.  It's disabled in the settings menu and I've tried the trick of turning filevault off and back on.  Find my mac is turned off.

I've attached a screenshot of the login screen.  Notice how the the account to the left has a distorted logo.  Both ask for passwords when selected.

[image]

Comment: That is quite weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I had re same issue but I didn't have two guest user accounts but I know how to remove them go to System presences> Users&Groups then click on login options then click on network join then open directory utility then unlock the lock then click on directory editor then search guest and delete one of the guests.

To remove password from guest open terminal located in Applications>Utilities then type `sudo passwd guest` it will prompt new password then type 'f' then again type `passwd Guest` it will prompt 'old password' type 'f' as the password then it will prompt 'new password' don't type anything then again it will ask for 'Retype Password' again don't type anything. If you have any other problem comment below.

Comment: hey @Geek, thanks for the reply.  I can't see where to search after double clicking "Active Directory".  If I search in the "Active Directory Domain" I get "Authentication server could not be contacted."

Comment: I'm  Sorry you should have not clicked the active directory you should have clicked Directory Editor and then search for it and remove the duplicate guest user.I have edited my answer accordingly.